# How to construct a CCY gate in Qiskit

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit

How can one construct a CCY gate using gates which are native to Qiskit (CCX and single qubit gates). I was able to find the answer for CCZ gates, however guessing and testing until I can figure out CCY seems like a bad way to go.

Comment: could you list what are the gates native to Qiskit? Decomposing procedures depend on the allowed gate set. Also, are you asking "*How to construct a CCY gate using gates that are native to Qiskit*", or "*Is there a general procedure for decomposing arbitrary unitary operations?*" I would put one of these two questions in the title/body of the post, and remove the other one (on stackexchange it is encouraged to ask a single question per post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $\mathrm{CC} Y$, given that you have a decomposition for $\mathrm{CC} Z$ (or for $\textrm{CC} X = \mathrm{Toffoli}$), all you need is the relationship between $ X$,  $Y$, and $Z$:
$$ Y = R_z (-\tfrac\pi2) X R_z (\tfrac\pi2) = R_x (\tfrac\pi2) Z R_x(-\tfrac\pi2) $$
Then, given $Y = U P U^\dagger$ for some $P$ for which you know a decomposition for $\mathrm{CC} P$, simply do the analogous decomposition:
$$ \mathrm{CC}Y = (\mathbf 1 \otimes \mathbf 1 \otimes U) \mathrm{CC} P (\mathbf 1 \otimes \mathbf 1 \otimes U)^\dagger. $$
You can do this for any self-inverse unitary $V$ in place of $Y$ as well.